# Handling the locations info of Github users

Tags: python, string, github, location, geocoding

I am doing some analysis on Github users. In the analysis, I need to know where some person comes from(exact to city) via his personal info(I have got his personal info via Github API).

The trouble is as you know Github users fill their location info in an informal syntax with varying specificity, so the following location names are all allowed:

`San Francisco, ca

San Francisco, CA

San Francisco, United States

San Francisco, California, USA

San Francisco Bay Area

San Francisco, CA, United States

USA San Francisco`

Now I use the [WebService](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) provided by [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) to parse these informal location names and get the details(e.g. lat & lng) of "San Francisco".

Because they are different strings, my program think them different places, so for each string, it will invoke the Webservice once.

Are there any solutions to reduce the webservice request times? That is, if my program knows the names I list above are the names of the same place("San Francisco"), for all names, it  invokes the WebService only once.

Is String Clustering effective? Or probably some other efficient solutions?

Comment: Isn't this in part why you use an external service? To delegate the task of parsing city names to that service instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @SimeonVisserHow to deledgate?I just invoke the service to get my info now.

Comment: Which is what I mean: you pass a string to the service and that service figures out the location. In other words, you're now trying to do work that in reality the service should be doing.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thx a lot, but the WebService has a rate limit, you can't pass the string to the service as long as you meet a string, so what I want it to reduce the times of passing string to the service. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I understand that but going from many different strings to one canonical representation of a city is the hardest part. Looking up lat / lng is the easiest part. So if you're going to do the hardest part yourself you might as well create your own lookup service.